# Animating a window on startup

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I am trying to animate the window in startup but it doesn't seem to work, I have written the code below.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui

import sys

class AnimatedWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    """docstring for AnimatedWindow"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(AnimatedWindow, self).__init__()
        animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, "geometry")
        animation.setDuration(10000);
        animation.setStartValue(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 100, 30));
        animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QRect(250, 250, 100, 30));
        animation.start();


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = AnimatedWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Comment: `QPropertyAnimation` class is supported in `Qt 4.6` and above, what version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this code is, when you create an object of `QPropertyAnimation` it is destroyed by the python garbage collector after `animation.start()` statement as `animation` variable is a local variable, hence the animation does not take place. To overcome this problem you need to make the `animation` as member variable (`self.animation`)

Here is the updated code which works fine:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui

import sys

class AnimatedWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    """docstring for AnimatedWindow"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(AnimatedWindow, self).__init__()
        self.animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, "geometry")
        self.animation.setDuration(1000);
        self.animation.setStartValue(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 100, 30));
        self.animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QRect(250, 250, 500, 530));
        self.animation.start();

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = AnimatedWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Comment: I am updating this answer by giving the actual reason of the problem